# session not persisting firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase

when I reload the user signs out.
here's the code:

```
export const SignUp = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleSignup = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      await setPersistence(auth, browserSessionPersistence);
      const userCredential = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);

      navigate('/');
      await createUserDatabase(userCredential.user)
      console.log('User created successfully!');

    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Sign-up error: ' + err);

      switch (err.code) {
        case 'auth/network-request-failed':
          setError(
            'A network error occurred. Please check your internet connection.'
          );
          return;
        case 'auth/invalid-email':
          setError('Invalid email');
          return;
        case 'auth/email-already-in-use':
          setError('This email is already taken.');
          return;
        case 'auth/weak-password':
          setError('Password should be at least 6 characters.');
          return;
      }

      setError('An error occured when trying to create an account.');
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="background">
      <div className="center">
        <form onSubmit={handleSignup}>
          <input
            type="email"
            placeholder="Email"
            onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          />
          <input
            type="password"
            placeholder="Password"
            onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          />
          {error && <div className="error-message">{error}</div>}
          <button>
            {!loading && 'Signup'}
            {loading && <div className="loading-icon"></div>}
          </button>

        </form>
          <SignInWithGoogle />
          <p className="link">
            Already signed up?<Link to="/login">Login</Link>
          </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I searched how to set firebase persistence in react, but I only found a syntax that doesn't work anymore. Do I even need to do this? Is there a better way to keep signed in even when it reloads? I wanted it to be like a normal application that you don't need to sign in for weeks or more.